# bid timer for auction

Tags: php, cron

I need to set up an online auction . I tried with cron for bid timer but i am always getting a message in mail as permission denied.is there any other method to set the bid timer. Any one please help me.
             Thanks in advance.

Comment: eh? Cron would be the last place to implement such a timer.

Comment: @symcbean - the question was how to do it, not if that was a good approach or not.

Comment: ...and if the question was "How do I use a crowbar to decrypt SSL" should we still struggle to provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to simply add a field in your database containing the `end date & time`. The remaining time can then be calculated when you need to display it, and all auctions which have an end time in the past can be shown as closed.

There's no need for any scheduled jobs here. In fact, cron is the wrong tool for this job since a cronjob is not guaranteed to run at an exact point in time (or even at all if the server is rebooting at the time). You may however want scheduled jobs for sending out messages about ended auctions and similar stuff.

Comment: i need to send a mail to the user who win the auction.

Comment: Rose, that was not what you asked about. However, you may want to check what was causing the permission error. Check the permissions and owner of your PHP file, and check which user your cronjob is running as (it may be another user than the web server, in which case you may need to modify the file permissions).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a secret link which to fire up the cron event - access that secret link from a server where you have access to a cron service. If you don't have such a server, simply create a function which to be called each time somebody accesses your site. In that function, check to see if the difference between last access time and current moment requires a cron job to be started

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to why you would want to use cron as a bid timer but anyway here is my 5 pence on it all...

1) store the auction end within your database using a DATETIME field so that you can retrieve this date and time whenever you need it.

2) Within your webpage you should then use server side scripting (such as PHP) to retrieve the datetime from the database so that the javascript can then use this time to determine how long there is left until the auction is finished.

See these links:

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_create_a_javascript_countdown_timer_on_my_web_page.html

[Countdown timer-php+mysql+js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420455/countdown-timer-phpmysqljs)