# PHP/Javascript countdown script

Tags: php, mysql, live, countdown

Note ******* I want some one to fix it and tell me how they did it not tips on how to do it or coments about php nd java mixed in it *******

I have a countdown script that is working, but when it hits the target date the timer keeps on going to a negative time. I want it to stop on that target date and just display a finishing message. It's live on my site. I just need help editing the countdown script.

I want to keep the same layout. I need some help adding the finishing message and stopping it from going into the negative date, or just make it not display the 0days, 0 hours, 0mins, 0sec until the site's officially released. When that finally happens, I want it to display a message.

countdown script

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('EST'); ?>
<?php
// Define your target date here
    $targetYear  = 2011;
    $targetMonth = 9;
    $targetDay   = 1;
    $targetHour  = 20;
    $targetMinute= 00;
    $targetSecond= 00;
// End target date definition

// Define date format
$dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";

$targetDate = mktime($targetHour,$targetMinute,$targetSecond,$targetMonth,$targetDay,$targetYear);
$actualDate = time();

$secondsDiff = $targetDate - $actualDate;

$remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
$remainingHour    = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24))/60/60);
$remainingMinutes = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
$remainingSeconds = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinutes*60));

$targetDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$targetDate);
$actualDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$actualDate);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var days = <?php echo $remainingDay; ?>  
  var hours = <?php echo $remainingHour; ?>  
  var minutes = <?php echo $remainingMinutes; ?>  
  var seconds = <?php echo $remainingSeconds; ?>  
</script>
<body onLoad="setCountDown();">
<center><?php echo "$remainingDay days, $remainingHour hours, $remainingMinutes minutes and $remainingSeconds seconds";?> untill official release</center>
```

how its added on the site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    /* Union War */
    $("#Countdown2").load("http://imperialism.zxq.net/includes/process/uwcountdown.php");

    setInterval(function(){
        $("#Countdown2").load("http://imperialism.zxq.net/includes/process/uwcountdown.php");
    }, 1000);
});
</script>

<div id="uwCD" class="uwCD">
    <div id="Countdown2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so where's the script (ie: the `.js` file) you are using? Is it being included somewhere?

Comment: (1) the problem is in JavaScript (setCountDown function I would assume), but it's not in example that you provided. The solution is (probably) where you calculating remaining value, just add a condition which checks how much time is remaining.

(2) just as a side-note, not quite sure why do you need to mix php and javascript in this script. I think it will be nicer just to have it all in javascript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420455/countdown-timer-phpmysqljs/6804156

Comment: @sanmai
sorry but thats not what im doing its set to a target date and its not running from mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($targetDate != $actualDate && $targetDate > $actualDate) { 
echo "$remainingDay days, $remainingHour hours, $remainingMinutes minutes and $remainingSeconds seconds"; 
} else { 
echo "0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this [jQuery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html); just pass the PHP value to the jQuery plugin call.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($targetDate != $actualDate && $targetDate > $actualDate) {
echo "$remainingDay days, $remainingHour hours, $remainingMinutes minutes and $remainingSeconds seconds";
} else {
echo "0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using this http://www.timeanddate.com/counters/customcount.html everything is done for you and its worked fine and if anything you can just edit the look of the skin to fit your website